What do these bars and timer on defense missions indicate?
Defense missions on planets have two bars, one blue and one yellow, and a timer. What do they indicate?


A variety of these bars are visible on the Galactic War map. Each of them indicate the struggle between the Helldivers/Super Earth (blue) and the enemy forces (yellow/red). Depending upon where you look, these bars can mean slightly different things.
When viewing the Galactic War map at the Sector level, hovering over a Sector that's currently being fought in will show the following panel:

This one's pretty self-explanatory. The blue bar represents the amount of glorious democracy that has been spread in this sector, and the yellow bar represents how much more liberation is required before the Helldivers have obtained full control over this sector.
When zoomed in on a sector, each unliberated planet that's available to fight in looks like the following:

In this situation, the blue bar still represents how much liberation the Helldivers have achieved. However, the opposing bar (red in this instance) is directly relational to how much time remains to defend this planet (indicated above the planet itself). The longer this fight goes on without achieving 100% liberation, the bigger that red bar will grow.
The bars you indicated are the same bars in the above image, but displayed when you zoom into a particular planet to see the Operations it has available. Here's the same planet that I highlighted above, but when zoomed into the planet to see its Operations:

Each planet (currently) allows the Helldivers 24 hours to participate in Operations to successfully defend it. That red bar represents time's progression towards the end of that 24 hours.
The bar is just there to better represent how the Helldivers (players) are doing versus the enemy in relation to how much time is left to complete the defense of the planet.

Source for this information:

Personal experience
This Reddit comment by MudSama
This article by GamesRadar, written by Will Sawyer

